# obtain bootstrap correlation interval between one variable and all others in data frame

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to get bootstrap correlation parameters (interval and rho) between one variable (v) and all others (x,y,z). If I was only interested in the correlation itself (not boostrap) I would use the following formula.

```
df[,-1] %>% map(.,~cor.test(df$v, .))
```

How can we use a similar idea with bootstrap?

```
v<-rnorm(20,50,2)
x<-rnorm(20,2)
y<-rnorm(20,10,2)
z<-rnorm(20,10,2)

df<-data.frame(v=v,x=x,y=y,z=z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to run the tests like in the one run case. Then extract the estimate of rho and the confidence intervals. The function returns these values.

Use package `boot` to run the above `R` times, in the code below 5 times.

```r
set.seed(2022)
v<-rnorm(20,50,2)
x<-rnorm(20,2)
y<-rnorm(20,10,2)
z<-rnorm(20,10,2)

df<-data.frame(v=v,x=x,y=y,z=z)

library(magrittr)
library(boot)

boot_cor <- function(data, i) {
  d <- data[i, ]
  cor_list <- d[-1] %>% purrr::map(~cor.test(v, .))
  pval <- sapply(cor_list, `[[`, 'estimate')
  conf.int <- sapply(cor_list, `[[`, 'conf.int')
  out <- rbind(pval, conf.int)
  out
}

b <- boot(df, boot_cor, R = 5)
b$t
#>            [,1]        [,2]      [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       [,6]        [,7]       [,8]      [,9]
#> [1,] 0.10901729 -0.35040802 0.5261551  0.47729667  0.04408784 0.75941797 -0.28443711 -0.6456858 0.1808467
#> [2,] 0.17520115 -0.28978685 0.5732758 -0.01138502 -0.45163044 0.43331887  0.20238775 -0.2637551 0.5918977
#> [3,] 0.45951068  0.02132649 0.7496046 -0.42373326 -0.72947047 0.02312342 -0.09795514 -0.5180212 0.3601784
#> [4,] 0.08274794 -0.37344763 0.5067140 -0.26406702 -0.63265841 0.20206624 -0.32949464 -0.6737737 0.1323194
#> [5,] 0.18779791 -0.27781014 0.5819556  0.11815477 -0.34226148 0.53281673  0.16289648 -0.3013469 0.5647101

# maybe more readable
array(b$t, dim = c(5, 3, 3),
      dimnames = list(NULL, c("rho", "lower", "upper"), names(df[-1])))
#> , , x
#> 
#>             rho       lower     upper
#> [1,] 0.10901729 -0.35040802 0.5261551
#> [2,] 0.17520115 -0.28978685 0.5732758
#> [3,] 0.45951068  0.02132649 0.7496046
#> [4,] 0.08274794 -0.37344763 0.5067140
#> [5,] 0.18779791 -0.27781014 0.5819556
#> 
#> , , y
#> 
#>              rho       lower      upper
#> [1,]  0.47729667  0.04408784 0.75941797
#> [2,] -0.01138502 -0.45163044 0.43331887
#> [3,] -0.42373326 -0.72947047 0.02312342
#> [4,] -0.26406702 -0.63265841 0.20206624
#> [5,]  0.11815477 -0.34226148 0.53281673
#> 
#> , , z
#> 
#>              rho      lower     upper
#> [1,] -0.28443711 -0.6456858 0.1808467
#> [2,]  0.20238775 -0.2637551 0.5918977
#> [3,] -0.09795514 -0.5180212 0.3601784
#> [4,] -0.32949464 -0.6737737 0.1323194
#> [5,]  0.16289648 -0.3013469 0.5647101
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>